# Query where all the value is same for particular unique id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned database:

```
id  Value
1   A
1   B
1   B
2   A
2   B
3   B
3   B
```

**I want to**

1. those id's only where all the value against those id is "B". (i.e id `3` in this case)
2. using where `id!=A` while query but it give me all id's where both the value are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(value) = max(value) and min(value) = 'B';
```

If you have a separate table of ids, this might be faster:

```
select i.id
from ids i
where not exists (select 1 from idvalues iv where iv.id = i.id and iv.value <> 'B') and
      exists (select 1 from idvalues iv where iv.id = i.id and iv.value = 'B');  -- at least one B
```

This can take advantage of an index on `idvalues(id, value)`.

Comment: the first query should also work with an index on `idvalues(id, value).` in fact the first query can use it as a covering index.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . "Should" is of course true.  Getting MySQL to use indexes for aggregations seems really troublesome to me -- unless the most recent versions have made this simpler.